# “Holomorphic” bump function

Tags: cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry, complex-manifolds

I was wondering in what sense can I construct a holomorphic “bump function”? Now, of course we cannot really construct a holomorphic bump function in the usual sense, but I have a much rougher idea in mind of what is a bump function.

Consider two copies of the complex plane one above the other in $\mathbb{C}^2$. Consider a disk of radius $1$ in the top plane, and a disk of radius $2$ in the bottom plane whose center lies right below the center of the top disk.

I can clearly construct a smooth manifold which glues the boundary of the top disk to the boundary of the bottom disk, and all of whose derivatives vanish on said boundaries.

Such a smooth manifold cannot be holomorphic. However, I am trying to find a holomorphic approximation, allowing for some singularities.

(A) Can I find a holomorphic manifold which glues the boundary of the top disk to the boundary of the bottom disk, without asking the derivatives to vanish at the boundary?

(B) Can I find manifold which glues the boundary of the top disk to the boundary of the bottom disk, without asking the derivatives to vanish at the boundary, which is piece-wise holomorphic? Or holomorphic aside for say, a singularity curve or finitely many singularities?

(C) Can I find such a manifold where at all singularities, the angles are bounded?

My end goal is to be able to construct a manifold which (aside for the differenetiable structure) looks like a bump function, and which can later on be “smoothened out” along the singularities to have a bounded C^2 norm, while being holomorphic almost everywhere. Kind of like gluing together holomorphic things. I have quite a lot of flexibility in what I ask of this manifold, but unfortunately I have little background on knowledge on this topic. Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It's still not clear, at least to me, what kind of construction you want. I think the problem is too descriptive. Do you want a specific complex structure on a manifold? Or are you dealing with some boundary issue on certain pseudoconvex domains?

Comment: @LidingYao what I actually want is the following: consider $\mathbb{C}^2$, and consider a submanifold $i: (2\mathbb{D})\to \mathbb{C}^2$ given by $i(z)=(z, h(z))$, where $h$ is say $C^2$ smooth. However my restriction on $h$ is that $h|_{\mathbb{D}}\equiv (z,1)$, and $\int_{2\mathbb{D}\setminus \mathbb{D}} i^*\omega\geq 0$. This somehow approximates the notion of a bump function in a holomorphic way

Comment: Are you looking for plurisubharmonic function? In $\mathbb C^1$ it's the same as subharmonic.

Comment: @LidingYao I am not sure if a subharmonic function is what I’m looking for, it could be. Unfortunately this area is new to me and I am somewhat of a novice, trying to draw intuition from real geometry. Is a subharmonic function satisfying the requirements I listed? And thank you for your help!

Comment: I am more a harmonic analyst than a complex geometer. So the honest answer is, I don't know a good reference in my head that suits your background. But try these keywords and see how you can find in Google.

Comment: @LidingYao thank you for your time!